# How to specify vb6.exe location for nant

Tags: vb6, teamcity, nant, nantcontrib

I'm trying to migrate us from an old CruiseControl based build server to a new TeamCity one and having trouble with the old VB6 based components we still have.

We are using Nant scripts which is making the task easier but I've hit a roadblock with the vb6 nant task.  I've installed nant.contrib.tasks so that the tag is now being recognised but I'm still getting an error...

```
[Step 1/1] D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\d2bf2472d554430\VB6Web\VB6Web.build(157,8):
'vb6' failed to start.
[Step 1/1] Step VB6Web Build (NAnt) failed.
```

I understand that this error "'vb6' failed to start." generally means it cannot find the vb6.exe but I cannot see how to specify it in the script.

According to the doco., "exename" is "The name of the executable that should be used to launch the external program." but is specified as a "Framework-configurable parameter".  I've tried adding it to the vb6 tag as an attribute but that gave an Unexpected attribute error.

I just can't seem to find an example of how to specify the vb6.exe path as a Framework-configurable parameter anywhere... help, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to set (and aren't meant to set) the `exename` parameter, the NAnt task will find the VB compiler for you. The `exename` framework configurable parameter is actually defined in the abstract class `ExternalProgramBase`, which the `vb6` task inherits from.

The `vb6` task requires that the Visual Basic IDE is installed so it can use `vb6.exe`. It'll find `vb6.exe` by looking up `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\6.0\Setup\Microsoft Visual Basic\ProductDir`([refer the source code](https://github.com/nant/nantcontrib/blob/master/src/Tasks/Vb6Task.cs)).

Since you indicated that this is a new build machine and you are reinstalling software (e.g. NAnt Contrib), it is likely you haven't reinstalled Visual Basic on this new build machine. If you have installed it, check the registry key and follow the path, you might need to reinstall Visual Basic to repair the registry key.

Comment: Thanks for the info., I'll have to check that in the morning but at least I now know why I couldn't find out how to set it(!).

VB6 is fully installed and works fine via the IDE building the projects in question (as are the other versions of studio), that was one of the first things I checked, so it may be that the reg. key has become corrupt.

Other than that I may simply convert the scripts to use the exec tag to run the builds directly which would be a shame as I had hoped not to have to change them too much between servers.

I'll report back with my findings, thanks again.

Comment: Seems that, despite VB6 being installed and working on the box, that reg. key doesn't exist so that would explain the problem I'm having.  Thanks for your help mate, much appreciated.

Comment: Just to add to this:

The above key will exist on an x64 system under SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\6.0\Setup\Microsoft Visual Basic\ProductDir\.  

Comparing behavior between nantcontrib 0.91 and 0.92, it appears that 0.92 on an x64 system reads from SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\6.0\Setup\Microsoft Visual Basic\ProductDir and not from Wow6432Node.  Copying from Wow6432Node to the x64 registry hive seems to have caused nantcontrib 0.92 to find vb6.exe.  (I believe the version of nantcontrib to be the only difference in my test.)

Comment: I created an Issue (https://github.com/nant/nantcontrib/issues/34) and submitted a fix that will have nantcontrib check for the x86 and x64 paths.  Thanks to Jonathon Rossi for providing a link to the code file and Zeinrich for providing the x64 path.